# MongoDB converting string date to date object in nodejs aggregate query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo aggregation query in my nodejs application, here is the code.

```
var tz = params.tz || util.config.TZ.default_timezone;
  var fromDate = moment(new Date(params.from)).tz(tz).format();
  var fromTimeOffset = moment.parseZone(fromDate).zone();
  fromTimeOffset = fromTimeOffset * 60 *1000;
  var adjustTime = (-1) * fromTimeOffset  ;
  var match={"$match":{"t":{"$gte":params.from.toISOString(), "$lte":params.to.toISOString()},"type":"content_views"}};
  r.inject_match(match, req_query.where);
  var dashboard_query = [match, {$project: { kayp_views_cnt: 1, date: { $add: ["$t", adjustTime ] } }},
    {$group: { _id: { year: { $year: [ {'$add': ['$date', 0]} ]},
      month: { $month: [ {'$add': ['$date', 0]} ]},
      day: { $dayOfMonth: [ {'$add': ['$date', 0 ]} ]}},
      name: {'$first': '$date'},
      count: {'$sum': 1} }},
    {'$sort': {name: 1}},
    {$project: { _id: 0, count: 1, day_t: { $dayOfMonth: '$name'}, month_t: { $month: '$name'}, year_t: { $year: '$name'}}}] ;
```

Here i am trying to adjust the timings, the column "$t" from mongo collection is a date in string format. so i want to convert that to date date type so that i can add the adjusted time.

This is the sample collection data :

```
{
    "_id" : "29",
    "timestamp" : 1602700200006,
    "t" : "2020-10-25T04:30:00.00Z",
    "user_id" : "1",
    "user_name" : "Manu"
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? MongoDB is able to handle dates like that. In fact this is how dates are serialized.

Comment: There's no operator to parse a date in string format. You should change the `t` field to have date values instead of string values.